# Reaching a login limit over SSH - How can I open more than 11 sessions?

Tags: command-line, ssh, login, proxy

I have a SSH connection to my Ubuntu VPS. I use it to create a proxy tunnel and it works well. I use Nethogs and "w" command to monitor the traffic.

Nothing bad happens until I reach `@pts/11`. When that happens, I can log in (and proxy traffic works) but I cannot enter any commands.

If I login with any account from the sudo group, it popup "Server refused to allocate pty" and not let me write any thing. If I login with Root account, it also popup another message: "stdin is not a tty" and still doesn't let me write anything. And if I use `w` or Nethogs again, i can only see the latest session is `@pts/11` and no `@pts/12` no matter how many more sessions I open.

I tried a lot of different ways but still no luck. Here is what I've done so far:

- Add "MaxSessions 300" to /etc/ssh/sshd_config
- Add "maxlogins unlimited" and "maxsyslogins unlimited" to /etc/security/limits.conf
- Reboot a lot of times.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48527/ssh-inside-ssh-fails-with-stdin-is-not-a-tty

Comment: Could [edit] to explain how you're connecting? By all means skip the IPs/hostnames but it would really help to know what you're doing in order to replicate it.

Comment: I use Putty and SSH Protocol to connect through port 3843